# How do I access elements within a WPF window to alter them?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controls, dependency-properties, element

I have a wpf window that has two elements. A MediaElement and a TextBlock.  All I want to do is get access to the TextBlock to either change its text or toggle its visibility.  I want to do this from the code.  Is there anyway to accomplish this other than dependency properties and data binding?  I've spent hours looking at dependency properties and data binding and I just can't wrap my head around them or the example only shows binding to other XAML elements.  Usually they are about DataBinding in regards to something really complex and I'm still pretty new at this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can give a name to you TextBlock and manipulate it from the code-behind of your window:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" .../>
```

MyWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyTextBlock.Text = "Foo";
   MyTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: I guess my issue is that I need to access it from within a different window.  An event in that window is the trigger.

Comment: Then the SomeEventHandler method will be a handler for that event that is being raised in a different window.